# how to build and deploy the webpack micro frontend module federation project in angular

Tags: angular, webpack, micro-frontend, remote-registry, remote-repository

Please guide with the steps how to deploy the webpack module micro frontend project from angular on production server.
with the webpack.config.js routing and remote registry exposed to provide the third application URL to bind using cors.

Comment: https://www.angulararchitects.io/en/aktuelles/the-microfrontend-revolution-part-2-module-federation-with-angular/

Comment: https://dev.to/sbhuvane/micro-frontend-in-angular-using-module-federation-31om